# Keep fixed axes when rotating cube with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a cube made in html and css, with javascript, I rotate the cube when I press the arrows on the keyboard, the cube in general rotates correctly on the X and Y axes, however, when I locate on the top or bottom faces I try to turn it to the right or left (around the Y axis), it does not rotate correctly, it seems that it does it around the Z axis.

right arrow on top face
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I48cV.png"

left arrow on bottom face
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSGIL.png"

I would like the cube to turn correctly, regardless of the position it is in and to know if it is possible to keep the axes of rotation fixed or if there is some other alternative solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/Winplax/cxfe2ko3/10/

I have investigated this behavior and everything is due to the fact that each time the cube rotates the axes of rotation also do so, with the exception of the X axis (arrows up and down), which apparently is not affected in the rotation. I have tried to use the rotation around the Z axis in search of a solution but without any results so far.

I have also seen that they offer near solutions using the matrix3d ​​property, but with little clean results and some failures. I have also used the rotate3d property of css, but I have not managed to correctly implement the rotation with that property.

```js
(function () {
  var rotateY = 0, rotateX = 0;
  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
   // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    if (e.keyCode === 37) rotateY -= 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) rotateX += 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 39) rotateY += 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) rotateX -= 90;
    document.querySelector('.cube').style.transform = 'rotateX('+rotateX+'deg)'+'rotateY('+rotateY+'deg)';
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
 background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/blackorchid.png);
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s linear;
 transition: transform .5s linear;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.side {
 position: absolute;
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 border: 8px solid black;
 font: normal 50px Arial;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 200px;
 color: #000000;
}

.front {transform: translateZ(108px); background-color: #A5F84C;}
.back {transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(108px); background-color: #8EF8F2;}
.right {transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(108px); background-color: #F7AE3C;}
.left {transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(108px); background-color: #F569F7;}
.top {transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(108px); background-color: #FBF977;}
.bottom {transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(108px); background-color: #FF5757;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front">front</div>
    <div class="side back">back</div>
    <div class="side right">right</div>
    <div class="side left">left</div>
    <div class="side top">top</div>
    <div class="side bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware that this doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're working with 3d objects in a webpage, have you considered using the "three.js" library? It makes use of HTML canvas and WebGL to make creating 3d objects fast and painless.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I had already considered, the issue is that this cube represents the main base of a web page, so that each side of the cube contains images, text and links, and requires events such as click, onmouseover, among others, as well I'm not sure if the three.js library is the best alternative.

Comment: Fair enough - You are correct, 3D objects created with three.js are not very good at being used to hold elements. I will investigate further...

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher, I will be attentive.

Comment: Thanks. No promises, though. I have a newborn at home who may require my attention soon. In the meantime, I am thinking the solution might involve creating 3 cube objects - one side aligned (like the one you have) and one each for top and bottom aligned, respectively. Then, you could find a way to switch between them when someone pushes the UP or DOWN keys.

Comment: Do not worry, I understand, first things first :)
I think it's a good idea what you propose, although I'm not sure how to represent it in code, maybe when you have time you could better illustrate your idea. I thank you in advance.

Comment: No Problem. To be honest, I'm not completely sure how to code it yet either, but one of the advantages of being up all night with a baby is that I have plenty of time to research/practice things. I will work throughout the night on a solution.

Comment: hahaha you're absolutely right, I really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Ok. So what I'm thinking so far is that the first thing you need to do is register in the code (somehow) when the cube has been rotated along the x axis, and is either sitting at x+90 (top side) or x-90 (bottom side).
I found a functional (though rather convoluded) way to obtain the rotation value of the cube using only javascript. The exact process is at this link:
https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/
Make sure to read the comments to at least Chris Coyier's comment (4'th one down), as users have further perfected the formula. -- Continued below....

Comment: ... Continued from above -- My thoughs were that if you could use this to find out when the cube has been rotated to either the bottom or the top positions (+90 or -90), you could then write a series of "if statements" (like on the original cube) that handle the left and right rotations the same way as if you were starting from the front side. 
I know it's a lot of work, and I'm not sure exactly how to implement the "rotation getter" function, but I know that we only need to obtain the value of the X axis, so it should be at least feasible. --Continued below....

Comment: ...Continued from above -- You might not even need to worry about the scale and angle properties. I will continue to try and figure out how to implement this, but I hope this is at least a bit helpful for now.

Comment: Here is an example of that "rotation value getter" in a cleaner version in codepen. Nevermind the fact that their example uses what you would call a z-axis rotation, all that matters is that they obtain the rotation value.  Example is here: [link]https://codepen.io/jjeaton/pen/bzolH

Comment: How about using the `transform-origin` css property to create a transformation anchor around which the cube will rotate?

Answer (score 1):

This might end up being easier than my previous suggestions..... As with my previous comments, this is not an answer in itself, however I think it might be a big step in the right direction. I just had to post this as an "answer" to be able to post my code.

I updated your javascript to include Z-axis controls, using the left and right (4,6) NumPad keys. Code is here:

```
(function () {
  var rotateY = 0, rotateX = 0; rotateZ = 0;
  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40, Numpad4: 100, Numpad6: 102
    if (e.keyCode === 37) rotateY -= 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) rotateX += 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 39) rotateY += 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) rotateX -= 90;
    else if (e.keyCode === 100) rotateZ += 90; // Numpad 4 - use when on top or bottom
    else if (e.keyCode === 102) rotateZ -= 90; //Numpad 6 - use when on top or bottom
    document.querySelector('.cube').style.transform = 'rotateX('+rotateX+'deg)'+'rotateY('+rotateY+'deg) '+'rotateZ('+rotateZ+'deg)';
  }
})();
```

It seems you are correct that when you rotate the cube around the X-axis, the Y-axis and Z-axis rotate along with it, making the Y-axis behave like the Z-axis and vice-versa. Therefore I have added keys to control the Z-axis. When the cube is on the top or bottom side you can see that the Z-axis controls behave like the Y-axis controls do when it is "upright".

The glaring problem with this solution, however, is that it requires separate keys to navigate the cube properly when it is on its top or bottom side. I have attempted several forms of "if statement" and "state-checker" functions to try and "remap" the left and right keys to the Z-axis when the cube's `rotateX === 90 || rotateX === -90`, but my efforts have gone to no avail. Perhaps it is because I am tired. Maybe your fresh eyes can see a solution I cannot.

I hope somewhere, in all of what i've posted, you can find something useful. I'll keep working on it and if I find something, i'll let you know. However, if you find the solution before me, I would love to know what it looks like.

Good luck

Comment: Hi again Christopher, I apologize for my delay in answering you, I see that you made a lot of progress last night, I really appreciate it. Regarding your previous comments, I read Chris Coyier's article, "Get the value of CSS rotation through JavaScript" and I think it can be useful in the logic of the solution. The property "transform-origin" could also be, although I'm not sure how to apply it dynamically based on the rotation of the cube, however your idea of rotating on the Z axis with the two extra keys has given me new ideas.

Comment: I will work on these ideas and if I make any progress, I will let you know immediately. Again, I thank you for the effort you have put in the search for a solution.

Comment: No problem - doing this stuff gives me good practice with coding. I, as well, tried playing with transform-origin, thinking it had promise, but it seems to only let you choose whether the transform happens at the center or an edge, which still doesn't seem to help if the rotation happens on the wrong axis. Don't let my experience with it dissuade you though. Best of luck. I hope to hear good news.